# Java: Impact of using 'if' instead of while loop during an iteration

Tags: java

I have a code something like this

```
Enumeration parameterEnum = request.getParameterNames()
while(parameterEnum.hasMoreElements()){}
```

what is the difference if I change it from a while statement into an if statement?

Comment: if with break in a while(true) loop ?

Comment: Another way to go is to TRY IT. You have javac and you can try all kinds of stuff out. Then your question might either get answered, or you might say, "I'm getting this result... why?" Good luck.

Comment: Also note, while we're here: in Java, you should name your variable instances with lowercase names. So Enumeration parameterEnum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change it to an `if` it will either execute once or not at all - a `while` statement will execute indefinitely until `ParameterEnum.hasMoreElements()` returns false.

Comment: I figured it was a trick question. I'm feeling suspicious today.

Comment: I'm still pretty suspicious.  I think that was a homework question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking, the current code would keep running whatever is in the brackets until there are not elements. This assumes that what is in the brackets takes off elements. As literally shown above, it is an infinite loop and will never end.

If you convert the `while` to an `if`, then what is in the brackets will run only once.

If `Request.getParameterNames()` returns an "empty" whatever-it-is, then neither case will do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The **if** will be much, much faster!!! its complexity is `O(1)` and that of **while**'s is `O(N)`!!!

So, the larger the input is, the better it is to use an **if** instead of a **while** ;-)

Comment: I've never seen someone so excited about big-`O`.

Comment: and you haven't seen me watching pr0n!! xD

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of a `for` statement, not an `if`.

```
if(ParameterEnum.hasMoreElements()) {}
```

The `if` will only run once

```
while(ParameterEnum.hasMoreElements()) {}
```

the `while` will run continuously, unless you increment the `enum`.

the other option is `for`:

```
for(Enumeration paramEnum = Request.getParameterNames(); 
                              parameEnum.hasMoreElements();) {}
```

this is similar to the `while`, and will run for as long as the `hasMoreElements()` method returns true, so incrementing the enum with `nextElement()` is important.